# Access the private attributes in a inherited class in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a class `a` defined like this:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.__z = z
```

I also have another class `b` which inherits `a` defined like this:

```
class b(a):
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z, t):
        super().__init__(w, x, y, z)
        self.__t = t
```

Now if I had access `w, x, y` from within `b`, I could simply do:

```
self.w
self.x
self.y
```

But I can't do `self.z` or `self.__z` to access `z`. So my question is how can you access dunder values such as `z` from within class `b`

(I know python doesn't really have private variables and I could do `self._a__z` from within class `b` to access `z` but I'm looking for methods which would allow me to just do something like `self.z` to access `z` from inside `b`)

Comment: The whole point of making it private is to make that difficult. `_a__z` is the only way to do it.

Comment: *The whole point* of using double-underscore name-manglinbg is to prevent name collisions in subclasses. If you want to just use `self.z` then don't use double underscore name mangling. You are trying to have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: 1. If `z` is meant to be accessible in `b` then it should not be private, as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested. 2. If `z` is meant to be partially accessible (e.g. read-only) in `b` then you can use `getter`s and/or `setter`s just like in other OOP languages.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of ways you *could* solve the problem by changing the API of class `a` to expose it's `__z` attribute in some more inheritance-friendly way. For instance, you could make the actual mangled attribute name an implementation detail and have the public API be a `property`:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.__z = z

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.__z

    @z.setter
    def z(self, value):
        self.__z = value
```

But unless you're doing some validation or modification of the value somewhere in the property's code, you probably should just do away with the double-underscores and let the child class access `self.z` like it can `w`, `x` and `y`. **The simplest solution is to replace `self.__z = z` with `self.z = z`.** You can always change it later to use a `property` if you find you do need validation or something.

If you just want to *hint* that `z` is not part of the wider public API, but only for subclasses and other code that knows about the intimate details of `a`'s design, consider using a single underscore: `self._z = z`. This has no special effects in the interpreter, but the single-underscore serves as a sort of documentation that `_z` is an internal attribute and you should only mess with it if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you want to keep your code clean:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.__z = z

    def get_field(self):
        return self.__z
class b(a):
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z, t):
        super().__init__(w, x, y, z)
        self.__t = t

    def ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField(self):
        return self.get_field()


c = b(1,2,3,4,5)
print(c.ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField())
```

**Output**

```
4
```

Similarly, you can use a setter to change its value:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.__z = z

    def get_field(self):
        return self.__z
    def set_field(self,z):
        self.__z = z

class b(a):
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z, t):
        super().__init__(w, x, y, z)
        self.__t = t

    def ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField(self):
        return self.get_field()
    def ChildMethodWhichSettingParentField(self,z):
        self.set_field(z)



c = b(1,2,3,4,5)
print(c.ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField())
c.ChildMethodWhichSettingParentField(10)
print(c.ChildMethodWhichUsingParentField())
```

**Output**

```
4
10
```